# zsh: command not found: ts-node

Tags: ts-node

ts-node appears to be installed, the package is visible users/user/node_modules/ts-node, but when entering ts-node in the command line or trying to run a command I receive the error "zsh: command not found: ts-node".

installed via 'sudo npm install -g ts-node' ; have scoured the first 3-4 pages of google search but no solutions worked.

On a macbook, not sure what needs to be moved/how to move it around so that the system recognizes it's installed. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can use `npx ts-node` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$ npm init -y` on project folder, after run `$ npm install -g ts-node`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me on Mac: `yarn global add ts-node`. This will install `ts-node` globally and then it can be used without any issue.